# Delphi Indy server being hacked?

Tags: delphi, indy10

I have been handed the code for a Delphi 7 / Indy 9 server that listens on a specific tcp/ip port.

The server was "unstable" until I added a OnNoCommand event handler like so:

```
procedure TFormMain.IdTCPServer1NoCommandHandler(ASender: TIdTCPServer;
  const AData: String; AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
  LogMessage('Got unhandled command: ' + AData);
  AThread.Connection.WriteLn('ERROR Unhandled command');
end;
```

And the log now shows that the server is being called by an unknown source as if it was a web server. This happens often, at least once an hour!

```
2018-06-01 11:43:16 | Got unhandled command: GET // HTTP/1.1
2018-06-01 11:43:16 | Got unhandled command: TE: deflate,gzip;q=0.3
2018-06-01 11:43:16 | Got unhandled command: Connection: TE, close
2018-06-01 11:43:16 | Got unhandled command: Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5555 
2018-06-01 11:43:16 | Got unhandled command: User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.31
2018-06-02 18:39:00 | Got unhandled command: CONNECT 45.33.54.195:80 HTTP/1.0
```

My first question is: what can I do about this? Is there anything I can do to make the server more secure?

Comment: Very broad question. No magic bullet. Hard to advise you with so little context.

Comment: What else do you want to know?

Comment: For the command definition TCP server there is the `TIdCmdTCPServer` component in Indy 10 (which replies to the client by the `ReplyUnknownCommand`).

Comment: About all you can is have your `OnNoCommandHandler` handler detect when an HTTP request is being received, and take note of the client's IP:port and blacklist it, and then disconnect the client. In the server's `OnConnect` event, if a blacklisted client connects, disconnect it immediately. Or put the server behind a firewall and add the blacklisted clients to the firewall's restrictions.

Comment: @Victoria although what you say is true, it doesn't address the OP's question about what to do about the issue at hand.

Comment: @Remy Lubeau. Thanks, yes, that seems the logical approach.

Comment: @Victoria. Thanks for your answer. I did however edit the question subsequently to focus on the primary issue.

Comment: Depending what you are planning to use your server for - (dedicated to a specific client?) you can always make a whitelist, and disconnect everyone else that tries to connect by analyzing their ip address. Or require a "magic word" upon connecting, and again disconnect them if they fail to provide it.